# Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. import { QuantityPicker } from 'react-qty-picker';

Tags: react-native, expo

Problem:

I am using component QuantityPicker from 'react-qty-picker'
but it throws an error

> Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.  import { QuantityPicker } from 'react-qty-picker';

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { QuantityPicker } from 'react-qty-picker';


export default function TaskView()  {
    const getPickerValue = (value) => {
        console.log(value) // Here you can get the value of the Quantity picker
    }
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
           <View>
           <QuantityPicker smooth value={0} onpress={getPickerValue}/>
           </View>
                
        </View>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Blockquote after the end of Stylesheet.create

````
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',

    },

})```

> Blockquote //remove this

Blockquote //remove this
````

Strings not rendered within the Text component can often cause this

Comment: it's not a typo it's a typo

Comment: Please throw more light so i can understand better